# Yeoman - Errors With Grunt Server Command

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman

I already have npm and git installed on my Ubuntu machine.

I followed the instructions below when installing Yeoman and the generator-angular.

Kickstart Your AngularJS Development with Yeoman, Grunt and Bower (step by step tutorial)
http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

My ultimate goal is to lauch a simple app using twitter bootstrap, so I can take advantage of their pretty UI. :D

However, when I get to the portion to run `grunt server` (recently replaced by `grunt serve`), I get a rediculous number of errors:

[image: Terminal Errors: Looks like grunt is not installed, even though I just installed grunt!]

I was previously suffering from the issue described below:

Cannot install yeoman because 'generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings peerDependencies
https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1065

Luckily I was able to work around it by running `npm uninstall -g generator-karma && npm install -g generator-angular` and then `sudo npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower`.

However, now I've hit a wall with grunt appearing as if it's not installed at all.

Does anyone know if there is a specific location where grunt should be installed? 
Should I install it globally (using `-g`)?
Should I not install it globally (using `-g`)?

I don't understand what I'm doing incorrectly, but it must be something fundamental because the process is intended to be automated and simple.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something npm install would fix.  Looks like some of your dependencies didn't install.

Try it first without -g.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I run the `npm install` command by itself (with no reference to yo, grunt-cli, or bower) in my TestApp1 folder?  I think I read somewhere that the `npm install` command by itself is a fix for certain glitchy behavior, but I can't seem to find any good documenation on `npm install` by itself and I don't know what it does by itself (without a package explicitly stated: `npm install [package name]`.  Also, I tried running commands without the `-g`, but no luck.

Comment: `npm install` without a package name should fix any broken dependencies.  I should examine your packages.json file and bring in any missing components.  Of course this depends on the dependencies being correct in the json files.

Comment: `npm install` removes the fifteen or so errors.  But now the terminal stops before opening chrome (project site served locally) and prompts me to install ruby and compass.  I didn't need to install ruby or compass for a previous yo angular project I built... Not sure what to do.  I think installing ruby is overkill and not necessary.  Anybody else running into this?

Comment: If you are on ubuntu do `sudo apt-get install ruby-compass` and you should be good to go.  You need ruby to run compass and compass is going to compile your sass -> css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem definitely has something to do with compass and ruby. I was able to quickly build an angular app using yeoman when I opted not to install compass/sass for the app when prompted after typing `yo angular` at the terminal. After following the suggestions in this post, the last error I got was the following error:

Warning: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/rubie-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req‌​uire.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- compass (LoadError)  from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/rubie-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req‌​uire.rb:55:in 'require' from /usr/bin/compass:20:in 'block in ' from /usr/bin/compass:8:in 'fallback_load_path' from /usr/bin/compass:19:in '' Use --force to continue Although, --force doesn't help.

but fixed it by simply following [these instructions](http://compass-style.org/install/).